# lwp-rget changes file format automatically to .bin?

Tags: html, perl, filesystems, format, perl-module

I'm trying to recursively download a web site to a local directory. [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP)'s `lwp-rget` allows me to do this, but I'm having the following problem: it's saving all the files with the extension `.bin` instead of `.rpm`, `.xml`, `.html`, etc.

I've been trying to maybe use the `--keepext=application/xml` or any type but it continues to save the file as `.bin`. Is there any way to get `lwp-rget` to use better file extensions? Thanks.

---

Fixed it using Daxim's help. I can now call lwp-rget --keepext=application/octet-stream --hier *URL* and I recursively download all the files that appear in the website in the proper hierarchy to a local directory. Hope this helps to anyone having a similar problem. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Well the files exist in a server, and those files are example.rpm, log.xml and log.html. These files are downloaded in the same format if done manually, as in clicking on the link and it downloads into your Downloads folder. Now when you use lwp-rget, they get changed to .bin which is not the format I want them to be. I know I could maybe change it manually afterwards but I am trying to find a way to keep the original format that they are stored in. So yes, its changing its file extension from example.rpm to example.bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you use `--keepext` or not, the MIME type returned by the server will figure in the decision of which extension `lwp-rget` will use. So the first thing we should do to debug this is determine the MIME type returned. This can be done using

```
lwp-request -ed http://... | grep -oP 'Content-Type: \K.*'
```

If you want `lwp-rget` to use the extension from the URL, you need to specify this MIME type with `--keepext`.

If you don't, `lwp-rget` will determine which extension to use by calling [LWP::MediaTypes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aMediaTypes)'s `media_suffix`. For example,

- `.xml` will be used for `application/xml`
- `.html` will be used for `text/html`
- `.bin` will be used for `application/octet-stream`

Comment: I tried that command running it with my URL, it returned text/html as the Content-Type. I tried using that type in keepext but files would still have the .bin extension, contrary to using application/octet-stream, that gave the correct extensions. I used the method guess_media_type from LWP::MediaTypes and it returned application/octet-stream.

Comment: `guess_media_type` isn't used by `lwp-rget`.

Answer (score 1):

To influence the [`--keepext` option](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lwp-rget) globally, specify a [`.media.types` file](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3A%3AMediaTypes).

Comment: That did the job in a way. I used the guess_media_type function on the URL and it returned application/octet-stream. I added it to the --keepext option and it did the trick. Don't really understand as to how that works but apparently lwp-rget needs to be made apparent of what its processing, maybe it doesn't auto detect everything. Thanks alot.